# A graph-based tuple merge?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, bioinformatics

I have paired values in tuples that are related matches (and technically still in CSV files).  Neither of the paired values are necessarily unique.

```
tupleAB = (A####, B###), (A###, B###), (A###, B###)...
tupleBC = (B####, C###), (B###, C###), (B###, C###)...
tupleAC = (A####, C###), (A###, C###), (A###, C###)...
```

My ideal output would be a dictionary with a unique ID and a list of "reinforced" matches.  The way I try to think about it is in a graph-based context.

For example, if:

```
tupleAB[x] = (A0001, B0012)
tupleBC[y] = (B0012, C0230)
tupleAC[z] = (A0001, C0230)
```

This would produce:

```
output = {uniquekey0001, [A0001, B0012, C0230]}
```

Ideally, this would also be able to scale up to more than three tuples (for example, adding a "D" match that would result in an additional three tuples - AD, BD, and CD - and lists of four items long; and so forth).

In regards to scaling up to more tuples, I am open to having "graphs" that aren't necessarily fully connected, i.e., every node connected to every other node.  My hunch is that I could easily filter based on the list lengths.  I am open to any suggestions.

I think, with a few cups of coffee, I could work out a brute force solution, but I thought I'd ask the community if anyone was aware of a more elegant solution.  Thanks for any feedback.

Edit 1 for clarification: In the graph context, I have found an approach that I think would work - cycle detection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection).  If this rings a bell for anyone, I guess I'm trying to identify the cycles in a graph constructed from the paired values in the tuples.

Edit 2: Ok, here's the plan:
1) Take csv files and construct [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) for graph analysis
2) Perform [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on each node of incidence matrix (and complete a cycle by ending on the original node)
3) Try to maximize unique "letters" (A, B, C, etc - in my case, the letters represent species)
4) These max-species depth first searches are the lists in the dictionary

Comment: Can you have different values for some of the letters ? Like tupleAB[x] = (A0001, B0013)
tupleBC[y] = (B0012, C0230)

Comment: The letters A, B, C are constant (in my case, they represent different species, the numbers #### represent some gene within the species, and the paired values are pairs of matched genes between species).  The x, y, z are just meant to represent some row in the paired value data set.  Did that address your question?

Comment: your csv file describes on one line all matched genes between two species. It's possible to create graphs reprensenting these relations, and it would result in several graphs (certainly complete graphs) each one representing a particular gene shared across many species. So your problem should be finding all connex compound. Am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution I'm reaching.  I'll add this above as another edit, but my approach at this point is to take my csv files, construct an incidence matrix, and perform a depth first search on each node.  In theory, I should be able to implement some edge length cutoff value (or some way to maximize species) and only have the genes spanning the most species.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is Warshall's variant of Floyd's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

This will find all reachable pairs in your graph in O(n^3) time.